# hadoop-streaming : Python import problems

Tags: python, hadoop, hadoop-streaming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Hadoop cluster - Do I need to replicate my code over all machines before running job?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892950/hadoop-cluster-do-i-need-to-replicate-my-code-over-all-machines-before-running)

I have a a mapper which when run in isolation runs fine, but when run with hadoop command gives **ImportError**

**Code:**

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/work/dw/a/src'))
    from src.utilities import utilities
    from src.utilities import PropXMLReader

    main()
```

when I run on **command-line**

```
>> import os, sys
>>> sys.path.append(os.path.expanduser('~/Documents/work/dw/a/'))
>>> from src.utilities import utilities
>>>
```

When running with hadoop I see errors as following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/app/hadoop/tmp/mapred/local/taskTracker/hduser/jobcache/job_201110271425_0003/attempt_201110271425_0003_m_000020_0/work/./mapper.py", line 55, in <module>
    from src.utilities import utilities
ImportError: No module named src.utilities
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.map(PipeMapper.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:50)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:255)
java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:311)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:545)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:132)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapRunner.run(MapRunner.java:57)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRunner.run(PipeMapRunner.java:36)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:261)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1059)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:255)
```

Comment: isn't it the same as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892950/hadoop-cluster-do-i-need-to-replicate-my-code-over-all-machines-before-running/

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate and Praveen's answer still seems to be the most likely cause. Voting to close.