# Python Hadoop streaming with import package that are not installed on data nodes

Tags: python, hadoop, streaming, hadoop-streaming

I tried to import scikit image in python hadoop streaming, and I've tried out existing posts on stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7892950/hadoop-cluster-do-i-need-to-replicate-my-code-over-all-machines-before-running/) and [here](http://eigenjoy.com/2009/11/18/how-to-use-cascading-with-hadoop-streaming/), but none of them solve my problem.

The real question is, even if I distributed using -file the zip/mod file with the packaged scikit-image folder, how does the python scripts that are running on data nodes know how to extract those packages and import into the code? 
Note that I've installed my python scikit-image on my name node , and I was able to run the local experiments.

My script is trivial: the classic  word count example for python streaming, with an extra "import skimage" in the mapper.py.
http://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/writing-an-hadoop-mapreduce-program-in-python

---

My command :

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar \
-file mapper.py    -mapper mapper.py \
-file reducer.py   -reducer reducer.py \
-file ./skimage.mod \
-input /user/text/* \
-output /user/textoutput/
```

---

Screen printouts:

```
packageJobJar: [mapper.py, reducer.py, ./skimage.zip] [/usr/lib/gphd/hadoop-mapreduce-2.0.2_alpha_gphd_2_0_1_0/hadoop-streaming-2.0.2-alpha-gphd-2.0.1.0.jar] /tmp/streamjob6159562120374599467.jar tmpDir=null
14/04/04 18:00:02 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
14/04/04 18:00:02 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
14/04/04 18:00:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is inited.
14/04/04 18:00:03 INFO service.AbstractService: Service:org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.YarnClientImpl is started.
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN snappy.LoadSnappy: Snappy native library not loaded
14/04/04 18:00:03 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
14/04/04 18:00:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: number of splits:2
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.jar is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.jar
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.value.class
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.mapoutput.value.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.value.class
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.job.name is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.name
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.input.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.input.fileinputformat.inputdir
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.output.fileoutputformat.outputdir
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.map.tasks is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.maps
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.cache.files.timestamps is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.cache.files.timestamps
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.output.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.output.key.class
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.mapoutput.key.class is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.map.output.key.class
14/04/04 18:00:03 WARN conf.Configuration: mapred.working.dir is deprecated. Instead, use mapreduce.job.working.dir
14/04/04 18:00:03 INFO mapreduce.JobSubmitter: Submitting tokens for job: job_1384839777050_0106
14/04/04 18:00:04 INFO client.YarnClientImpl: Submitted application application_1384839777050_0106 to ResourceManager at hdm3.gphd.local/172.28.9.252:8032
14/04/04 18:00:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: The url to track the job: http://hdm3.gphd.local:8088/proxy/application_1384839777050_0106/
14/04/04 18:00:04 INFO mapreduce.Job: Running job: job_1384839777050_0106
14/04/04 18:00:08 INFO mapreduce.Job: Job job_1384839777050_0106 running in uber mode : false
14/04/04 18:00:08 INFO mapreduce.Job:  map 0% reduce 0%
14/04/04 18:00:12 INFO mapreduce.Job: Task Id : attempt_1384839777050_0106_m_000001_0, Status : FAILED
Error: java.lang.RuntimeException: PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(): subprocess failed with code 1
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.waitOutputThreads(PipeMapRed.java:320)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapRed.mapRedFinished(PipeMapRed.java:533)
    at org.apache.hadoop.streaming.PipeMapper.close(PipeMapper.java:130)
```

---

I checked the error log in the hadoop job, it's complaining it cannot find "import skimage" which means it's not picked up by the data nodes.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the `zipimport` solution?

Here is an example: [Hadoop: How to include third party library in Python MapReduce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15352981/hadoop-how-to-include-third-party-library-in-python-mapreduce)